# What anime are all of these fruits from?

Tags: koi-to-senkyo-to-chocolate

This is a picture of some fruits from an anime:

[image: yum, delicious fruity foodstuffs]

Can anyone identify what anime this is, and what episode?

Comment: -1. I think this question is quite random...

Comment: This questions has three close votes. I voted to leave it open, just because it was already decided here: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/507/fruits-questions-that-need-to-be-closed-or-deleted

Comment: All three close votes are for "Not a real question" which says in its description "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." I really don't see how that applies here at all. Admittedly, it's not a very good question (see [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/510/april-fools-2013) if you're wondering why I even asked it) but definitely a real question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears in episode 4 of [**Koi to Senkyo to Chocolate**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/12175/Koi_to_Senkyo_to_Chocolate), about 5:40 seconds in, during a sequence when [Nozomi Edagawa](http://myanimelist.net/character/63477/Nozomi_Edagawa) is talking about food.

Answer (score 0):

These are all characters from [**Koi to Senkyo to Chocolate**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/12175/Koi_to_Senkyo_to_Chocolate)

From left to right these are the following characters:

Back row:

- Lemon
- Melon
- Pineapple
- Melon (whole)
- Bananas

Middle Row:

- Grapes
- Strawberries
- Pear
- Melon

Front Row:

- Orange
- Apple
- Kiwi